# mysql restore root PRIVILEGES

Tags: mysql, database, root

While trying to navigate or learn more about users in mysql phpmyadmin I accidentally removed the ***PRIVILEGES*** of the user root. Now i cant create new database, new user, etc. How can I restore the ***PRIVILEGES*** to user root again

1. What I wanted to do when I made my mistake is to create a sole user for one of my database.I wanted to remove the ***PRIVILEGES*** of root for that specific database only and not for everything. It seems that I remove the ***PRIVILEGES*** of root for the entire mysql.

`Tried`

```
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET Grant_priv='1' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

`Getting`

> Error
>   SQL query:
>
> USE mysql;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

`Tried`

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

`Getting`

> Error
>   SQL query:
>
> UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv =  'Y',
>   Super_priv =  'Y' WHERE User =  'root';
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1142 - UPDATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'user'

`UPDATE`

I tried creating new user

`CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user';`

and i get this error

> ## 1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

`tried`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'qwe';
```

`getting`

> ## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you've deleted your root user by mistake you can do one thing:

1. Stop MySQL service
2. Run mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
3. Type mysql -u root -p and press enter.
4. Enter your password
5. At the mysql command line enter: use mysql;
   Then execute this query:

   ```
    INSERT into user (`Host`, `User`, `Password`, `Select_priv`, `Insert_priv`, `Update_priv`, `Delete_priv`, `Create_priv`, `Drop_priv`, `Reload_priv`, `Shutdown_priv`, `Process_priv`, `File_priv`, `Grant_priv`, `References_priv`, `Index_priv`, `Alter_priv`, `Show_db_priv`, `Super_priv`, `Create_tmp_table_priv`, `Lock_tables_priv`, `Execute_priv`, `Repl_slave_priv`, `Repl_client_priv`, `Create_view_priv`, `Show_view_priv`, `Create_routine_priv`, `Alter_routine_priv`, `Create_user_priv`, `ssl_type`, `ssl_cipher`, `x509_issuer`, `x509_subject`, `max_questions`, `max_updates`, `max_connections`, `max_user_connections`) values('localhost','root','','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','','0','0','0','0');
   ```

then restart the mysqld

Comment: how do i start the mysql service?do i do it in cmd?i am using windows.if in cmd how can i run the mysqld_safe?sorry very new to database. I think i didnt not delete the root..i just removed the privileges. because i can see that i am currently log in as root

Comment: in windows , go to Services,there you will find list of services with their status. Go to MySql Right click and click on Stop.

Answer (score 0):

For MariaDB 5.5.56 and perhaps others, the command needs to be:

```
INSERT into user (`Host`, `User`, `Password`, `Select_priv`, `Insert_priv`, `Update_priv`, `Delete_priv`, `Create_priv`, `Drop_priv`, `Reload_priv`, `Shutdown_priv`, `Process_priv`, `File_priv`, `Grant_priv`, `References_priv`, `Index_priv`, `Alter_priv`, `Show_db_priv`, `Super_priv`, `Create_tmp_table_priv`, `Lock_tables_priv`, `Execute_priv`, `Repl_slave_priv`, `Repl_client_priv`, `Create_view_priv`, `Show_view_priv`, `Create_routine_priv`, `Alter_routine_priv`, `Create_user_priv`, `Event_priv`, `Trigger_priv`, `Create_tablespace_priv`, `ssl_type`, `ssl_cipher`, `x509_issuer`, `x509_subject`, `max_questions`, `max_updates`, `max_connections`, `max_user_connections`) values('localhost','root','','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','','0','0','0','0');
```

Adding `Event_priv`, `Trigger_priv` and `Create_tablespace_priv`.